# How to create local notification for ionic app?

Tags: angularjs

I am using Ionic v1 and angularjs for my mobile app, I am storing some dates in `localStorage`. Based on this date and time user should get notification.
Can any one please suggest me how to proceed with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `ngCordova local notification` documentation here

[ngCordova local notification](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/localNotification/)